# Large React project, how to keep multiple fetch requests DRY

Tags: javascript, reactjs, architecture

How do I keep a project with over 40 fetch requests (with similarly structured JSON responses) DRY in React? *Copying-and-pasting fetch-then-catch doesn't seem right...*

Comment: This bears an eerily resemblance to your last question....haha. The answer is more complicated than you'd think, because in your last question you conflated 2 different things: the re-use of fetching logic and the sharing/availability of fetched data. So when it comes to the first point, then yes as per your last question, making a single reusable hook would help reduce vast amounts of repetition when it comes to doing a request to a URL and storing the data. As for the second point, it's a bit more complicated.....

Comment: We'd probably need more context as to the proposed "reusability" of the data, and whether it should be something that's stored in Redux/context or whether there's a better approach to it. You have a very general use case without much specifics, so giving a solution that's specific to you is hard

Comment: @Jayce444 Thank you. Sorry for repeating... I'm really stumped by this one lol. The fact that there is no single answer or best practice worries me because what I'm doing seems like spaghetti code and I want to make sure the next guy inherits a code base that'll keep him sane... The fact that I'm using Math.random() is even more worrying...  I guess I'll keep useFetch in each component that needs it and if the app scales a lot I'll use redux/context... Coming from Django, I somewhat expected React to be more opinionated but that's not the case lol... Thanks once again :)